# Qt: How to build a qt librabry project within an application project

Tags: qt

I have a qt library project that I want to use in several Qt application projects. The application project however should build the library as well, if its not already built. Is that possible?

The accepted answer in the following question shows how to create the library and application projects. I guess one has to build the library first before one can use them in the application projects:
[What is the easiest way to reference libraries in Qt projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870637/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-reference-libraries-in-qt-projects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way by using the subdirs template:
I have now a pro file with TEMPLATE=subdirs that lists the different pro files I want to build.

The subdirs pro file is like a solution file in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set project dependencies.
If using Qt Creator: -

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.2/creator-build-dependencies.html

Else, you can edit the .pro files directly and do something like this: -

http://dev.modmancer.com/index.php/2010/11/14/qmake-building-dependencies/